# Is it possible to read Apple .pkpass wallets through NFC reader application in Android device?

Tags: android, ios, nfc, wallet, google-pay

I have created an Android application for reading Google PayPass event tickets through NFC. Now my task to learn how to read a similar way but Apple Wallets tickets. Is it possible? And how exactly to do it?